# Efficiency of quasiconvex optimization

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, machine-learning, numerical-optimization

Summary: Could we minimize quasiconvex objectives in polynomial time?

Whenever an objective function of an optimization problem can be formed as a convex function, this is considered as victory. Typically efficient algorithms for finding global optimum exists.

However, I have not seen this done for **quasiconvex** functions. What is the major difference between them, that makes the second undesirable from the optimization point of view?

Comment: you have to define what means "optimization in a polynomial time". with a convex function from the value of the function at a finite number of  points we can bound the localization of the global minimum. now look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiconvex_function#/media/File:Monotonicity_example2.png you'll see that if there are many bumps like that it doesn't work anymore, so the complexity of the gradient descent for such a function should be something like $N$ times the complexity of the gradient descent for a convex function (where $N$ is the number of such bumps)

Comment: $N$ times a polynomial is still a polynomial. Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think you understood "you have to define what means optimization in a polynomial time" : is the search set discrete or continuous ? if it is continuous, in the general case you can only give an approximation to the optimal solution. and if we don't know how large $N$ can be, we cannot bound the complexity of searching for an approximation to the optimal solution